# Let $(G, *)$ an algebraic structure such that binary operation $*$ is associative and for all $a, b$ elements of $G, a^2*b=b=b*a^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

> Let $(G, *)$ be a binary operation $*$ that is associative and for all $a, b \in G$ and $a^2*b = b = b*a^2$.
> Prove that $(G, *)$ is an Abelian group.

I was trying to solve this problem for my class.

My attempt:

Since $*$ already associative, I tried to find the identity element $e$ and the inverse element.

I found the $e$ to be $a^2$ for all $a$.
And the inverse element is $a^{-1}$ for all $a$.
Then $(G, *)$ is a group.

But then I was stuck at the commutative property $ab = ba$, my lecturer gave me a hint which is since $e=a^2$ then we can say that $e = (ab)(ab)$.
From there I work my way out and successfully proven the commutative property.

Now what I want to know is, could you start from somewhere else? i. e. the fact that $a^2*b = b = b*a^2$ or the inverse element $a^{-1}$ for all $a$. If you indeed can, could you please show me how/the process.

Comment: You can’t prove $G$ is an Abelian group; $G$ could be empty.

Comment: Please always include the question in *the body* of your post, not just in the title. In fact, it's best to make your title shorter and suggestive of the question, especially when it involves technical statement(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key of this question is that for all $a\in G$, $a^2=e$, that is, $a^{-1}=a$.

Let $x,y\in G$. Then $xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}=(yx)^{-1}=yx$.

Comment: You are assuming $G$ is nonempty (in which case this becomes a duplicate). But nothing in the set up warrants that assumption.